# What does "light weight" mean when discussing a framework

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I am learning Java EE frameworks, while studying i came across the term "Light weight" application or class.
What does this term refer to? How the people are saying this application is an light weight application? What are the criteria that makes an application "light weight"?

Comment: It's a buzzword meaning "easy and good".  :-)

Comment: It's marketing hype that may or may not mean anything.

Comment: usually i heard saying threads are lightweight and process is heavy weight

Comment: It means nothing whatsoever. Also, technically, Java EE is the framework. There's a bunch of other web frameworks that work over the Servlet spec which is *part of* Java EE, but the frameworks themselves I wouldn't count as such. (Honestly, Java EE itself is such a huge umbrella that applying it to any single thing tends to be meaningless.)

Comment: Basically, it could mean "low resource usage" - although I doubt most frameworks making that claim bothered to test, also startup time of a framework is usually dominated by the startup time of the containing appserver and of your application. I.e. if you have a five tier application that's overengineered to all hell your framework won't make it any faster. Or it could mean "straightforward API" which is a valid advantage but then again why not say that, or "low conceptual overhead" but that also tends to imply the framework doesn't actually do much.

Comment: To expand on the conceptual overhead comment - Rails is a textbook example. 0.x and 1.x were when Rails fans just would not shut up about how pointless and overcomplicated Java frameworks were. Now they're at 4.0, and ended up reinventing pretty much all the things they used to mock before. They might have reinvented them better, and contributed some great ideas to the web programming ecosystem (like migrations), but current Rails is hardly lightweight or easy to wrap your head around if you're intent on following the best practices. (Although it might scale down for simpler use cases.)

Answer (score 4):

There's not an agreed upon usage for it, but it typically invokes the idea that

- It requires fewer dependencies on other libraries and APIs
- Has less configuration and setup
- May be faster at the expense of having fewer features

A good example might be comparing the "lightweight" Spring framework with older EJB standards.  Spring introduced the idea of using annotations to inject business logic into the code, along with auto-wiring.  EJB, on the other hand, used to require a lot of configuration, dependence on JNDI API, and had to run within an application server.

Just so people don't find me to be biased, EJB 3.1 has improved things greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically think of "light weight" as referring to low resource consumption (CPU, memory, network bandwidth, file handles, etc.).

But someone else might write a really bloated application, but create a simple API for it, and declare it "light weight".

You're right to question what it means, but unlikely to get a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

Light weight is usually referring to its memory footprint, install size, or even startup time.  If one framework only uses 30MB to run while the average framework takes 100MB+ to run, then it can claim that it's light weight.  Similarly, if it only takes .5 seconds to run compared to an average of 5s, then it can make the same claim.  They usually define light weight though.

Answer (score 0):

lightweight means a solution/technic that avoids unessearry memory / objects or more general: resource consumption. 
It usually a more intelligent solution.

(Although better and faster algorithms (with better worst case behavior) are not called leightweight)

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight can also be used to describe a library which intentionally lacks features in order to provide a simpler API or have fewer external dependencies.  For instance an HTML parser that lets you get elements by tag, ID, or class, but doesn't let you write your own XPath queries might be called lightweight, particularly if the user does not have to install as many or any additional libraries in order to use it.

As others have said, lightweight libraries generally also offer lighter resource consumption for the same reasons.